# How to understand this currying function with typescript interface

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I think I understand a bit [currying function](https://gist.github.com/donnut/fd56232da58d25ceecf1). I am confused with the `=` in  `(response: any) => ITest = (response)`

Could someone explain it?

A bit more code

```
export interface ITest {
    type: string;
    payload: any;
}

export const callApi: (response: any) => ITest = (response) => ({
    type: 'CALL_API',
    payload: response
});
```

**Update 1:**

I tried to write it step by step, is it correct?

```
export const callApi: (response: any) => ITest
```

Then this assigns to the interface?

```
(response) => ({
  type: 'CALL_API',
  payload: response
})
```

Comment: There is no currying here. Just a variable declaration and initialization.

Comment: This is not function currying, `(response: any) => ITest` is a type. what after `=` is the function

Comment: It's `export const <name>: <type> = <value>`

Comment: *"is it correct"* - what did the compiler say?

Answer (score 0):

The = is to assign the value (in this case a function ) to the variable callApi. Just that. Nothing else

Comment: Are you able to write it in step by step?